# Getting result from ShowDialog without resorting to code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm implementing code from the excellent answer to this question [WPF + Castle Windsor + MVVM: Locator-DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899863/wpf-castle-windsor-mvvm-locator-datacontext-problem/5947031?noredirect=1#comment37587174_5947031). I'm not sure how to get the value from `ShowDialog()` though without resorting to code behind (which breaks testability), anyone have any ideas?

I was using this class with the MVVM Light `Messenger` class and it was working fine, but entails using the Service Locator anti-pattern.

EDIT

The current code I have that isn't working is

DataSourcePicker.xaml.cs

```
public DataSourcePicker(IDataSourcePickerViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _viewModel = viewModel;
    DataContext = viewModel;
    Closed += (s, a) => RaiseDismissed();
}

public event Action OnDismissed;

private void RaiseDismissed()
{
    if (OnDismissed != null)
        OnDismissed()
}
```

in DataSourcePicker.xaml

```
<Button IsDefault="True" .../>
```

in MainViewModel.cs

```
public void NewDataSource()
{
    var viewModel = _dspViewModelFactory.ResolveDataSourcePickerViewModel();
    var view = _dspFactory.ResolveDataSourcePicker(viewModel);
    view.OnDismissed += () => NewDataSourceImplementation(viewModel);
    view.ShowDialog();
}
```

I need some way to set the IsAccepted property on the DataSourcePickerViewModel to true when the user clicks the button

Comment: If I had to guess, you just need to change the signature of "RaiseDismssed" to be a `Func<DialogResult>` instead of an `Action` Does that sound like what you need?

Comment: DialogResult isn't a type, ShowDialog returns a bool? - that's nullable bool, not a question

Comment: Ok, `Func<bool?>` same question, is that the change you want to make?

Comment: If I understand the other answer correctly, the method fed to OnDismissed is the method that will run after the dialog is shown, I need to get the result from ShowDialog before I run that method to determine if the user accepted or cancelled the dialog box

Comment: The I don't actually see a call to ShowDialog in that code, so I'm guessing, but OnClose sounds like an event that would contain the result. If it does, you could use "s" or "a" from the example and pass it to OnDismissed. Could you show the code that you want to work, and where you are confused or it isn't working?

Comment: I don't have an IDE to check this stuff out, and it's been 2-4 years since I've done MVVM or other .Net code. But: I think I'd bind the dismissing button's command to an `ICommand` on the view model that sets the appropriate value for `IsAccepted`, and then have that command also raise the `OnDismissed` event. This allows you to avoid the specific behavior of views/`ShowDialog`, which is part of what you're trying to do in this whole MVVM thing.

Comment: I thought about that. If I do that though, how do I close the view? That would still require code behind right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have neglected to show your implementation of "ShowDialog" or explain how your `DataSourcePicker` shows up in the application, it is difficult to give you a clear solution; So, here are two options depending on your implementation of `DataSourcePicker`:

In the unlikely event that your `DataSourcePicker.ShowDialog` method simply invokes `MessageBox.Show`, your solution is simple.

```
    public void NewDataSource()
    {
        var viewModel = _dspViewModelFactory.ResolveDataSourcePickerViewModel();
        var view = _dspFactory.ResolveDataSourcePicker(viewModel);
        var result = view.ShowDialog();
        if (result.HasValue)
        {
            viewModel.IsAccepted = result.Value;
        }
    }
```

However, if you have implemented your `DataSourcePicker` as a custom Modal dialog window, or you do not close the dialog window immediately after `ShowDialog` has executed, the solution becomes more complex.

In this scenario, you will have to add an `ICommand` to your viewmodel.

```
class DataSourcePickerViewModel : IDataSourcePickerViewModel
{
    public bool IsAccepted { get; set; }
    public ICommand NewDataSourceCommand { get; private set; }

    public DataSourcePickerViewModel()
    {
        NewDataSourceCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            IsAccepted = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Then, you will have to update your `DataSourcePickerView` with:

```
<Button Command="{Binding NewDataSourceCommand}"
        Content="Close"/>
```

Otherwise, you will need to Use one of the following solutions for binding commands to events:

- [MVVM Light - EventToCommand](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/SL5/html/fa15acb6-eab0-4873-4cf6-e7ecbfe05d37.htm)
- [MSDN - EventToCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)
- [Marlon Grechs AttachedCommandBehavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/)

Then, you would update the view like so (If using the AttachedCommandBehavior library):

```
<ModalControl x:Class="_24318313.DataSourcePicker"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_24318313"
              mc:Ignorable="d" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:DataSourcePickerViewModel}"
              local:CommandBehavior.Event="Close"
              local:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding NewDataSourceCommand}"
              d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"/>
```

If you feel this doesn't solve you issue, please let me know and I will update in response to your feedback; Otherwise, please mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: Adding the command was the initial way I attempted to solve the problem. I got hung up because I couldn't figure out how to close the dialog, I just resorted to adding this.Close() in the OK button's click event handler. Thanks